# How to find commit when file was deleted?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket, git-commit

I just realized a file that I had a long time ago was deleted, and I want to find the specific commit in which it was deleted. I'm using Bitbucket and VsCode.

Comment: note: see *all* the answers in the duplicate, not just the first / accepted one, for various hints.